# ActiveX Spell Check component for legacy VB6 App

Tags: vb6, activex, spell-checking

I was tasked this morning to find a replacement spell check ActiveX component to be used in one of our legacy VB6 applications. I have been searching and searching but I am not finding anything worth mentioning here.

Does anyone have any ideas and/or experiences with any ActiveX spell checker components. We are currently using [Chado SpellText ActiveX component](http://174.123.20.5/download/chado-spelltext-v2-3-19040.html) but we are receiving reports from our customers that are running our app on a Win7 64 bit machines a very noticeable lag whenever they are typing data into the control.

Comment: Is Microsoft Word available to the client? It's easy to use Word for your spell checking.

Comment: In most but on not all of our customers have MS Word installed but we need a control that doesn't depend upon MS Word being present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [VSSpell](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/VSSPELL/) from ComponentOne. We've had it for awhile and are currently using version 6.0, but (surpisingly) the latest version is still an ActiveX component and therefore should work fine in VB6. The control is relatively easy-to-use and comes with full documentation.

I'm not sure if this is different in the latest version, but one thing I don't like about it is that the red underline support is a little bit lacking (and because of that, we don't use that feature). Specifically, unlike Word, when you enable the display of a red underline for misspelled words, the underline only stays visible for one word at a time. For example, if you type "speling", it will underline the word, but as soon as you type the next word, the underline is removed, so you can only "see" one misspelled word at a time as you type.

Other than that slight nit-pick (which may or not matter to you), it works perfectly fine and has never caused problems for us.